# Позиция курсора в блоке x, y Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как получить положение курсора в блоке, относительно этого же блока? тобишь `x` и `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос ищется по банальному запросу в Google типа "cursor position in div jquery", например [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element):

```
$("#something").click(function(e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
});
```